# Spring Integration: inbound and outbound adapters to MQTT

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt

I'm trying to build MQTT support into my Spring application. For this I'm looking at the references provided by Spring, which can be found here [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html).

They provide sample code for inbound and outbound channel adapters, but this concept of adapters is unclear to me. I couldn't find a lot of information about it on the web.

What exactly are these adapters and why are they needed?

Where do I need to define these adapters and how do I access them?

I'm using eclipse as my IDE and maven as my buildtool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapters are a concept from [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html) which is yet another Spring project that provides an implementation of the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns) and provides an abstraction layer that standardizes the way you integrate with external system, whether they are based on JMS, FTP or as in your case MQTT.

As with so many other Spring projects, the driver behind it is a loose coupling and standardization that will enable you to swap your channel provider (e.g. if its a JMS provider swap RabbitMQ with ActiveMQ or vice-versa) with a minimal impact to the rest of you code.

Its comparable to Apache Camel, in case your more familiar with it, and this [comparison](http://java.dzone.com/articles/light-weight-open-source) is quite an interesting read